# The physics package does not "see" brackets in math mode when compiling, but if I remove them it does work

Tags: latex

I have the following text on overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \dv{t} \ev{f[x(t)]} = \ev{\pdv{f}{x} a[x(t),t] + \frac{1}{2} \pdv[2]{f}{x} (b[x(t),t])^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

but when I compile it I have the following output

[image: Image of the output]

But if I try the same text without round brackets

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \dv{t} \ev{f[x(t)]} = \ev{\pdv{f}{x} a[x(t),t] + \frac{1}{2} \pdv[2]{f}{x} b[x(t),t]^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I get the right output [image: Right output]
It's also working with square or curly brackets, the only problem is with round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physics package actually uses round parenthesis as a special syntax to get the long form of the partial derivative. However this syntax is instead of the `{f}` and not in addition to it, so only one pair of `{...}` before them:

[image]

You can avoid the problem like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \dv{t} \ev{f[x(t)]} = \ev{\pdv{f}{x} a[x(t),t] + \frac{1}{2} \pdv[2]{f}{x} \left(b[x(t),t]\right)^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```